# Page header & footer on Summary band

Tags: jasper-reports

I have read this thread:

http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=67923

I would rather not repeat the page header and footer for each crosstab, as there are six of them, and if the header needs to change, I'd like to change it only once.

The problems include:

- Putting the crosstabs on their own page (should be easy enough with a page break).
- Making the crosstabs include the same header and footer as the rest of the report.
- Reusing the header & footer from a single source.
- Making the crosstab be shown before the data (not all that important, but would be nice).

The report appears as follows:

[image]

---

[image]

---

It would be fantastic to have the crosstab appear on a page by itself, including the same header and footer as the rest of the report, rather than looking like the image above.

The report is set up as follows:

---

[image]

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involved these changes:

- Provide a dummy query for the main report (e.g., SELECT 1 FROM DUAL)
- Create a new subreport for the data details, based on the former query for the main report
- Add a second detail band (Detail 2)
- Place the six subreports in the first detail band (Detail 1)
- Place the data details subreport in the second detail band (Detail 2)
- Pass the parameters from the main report into the data details subreport
- Reduce the data details subreport's margins to zero
- Delete the Summary band (no longer required)

This allows full control over the crosstab's report position while reusing the same header and footer for both the crosstab and the data details.